# Why are my plots connected - how to plot on multiple figures in a for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, subplot

I am new to Python and trying to re-write some of my previous MatLab scripts. I am running into issues plotting within a for-loop. My first plot is 3D and my second plot is 2D. For some reason the plots are all connected.

Main problem: I think there is a problem with the way the x3table and y3table are being created. They should be cleared and reset to the initial conditions for each value in lst.I'm not sure why I get the horizontal line across the top of the plot.

[Solved using comment from TMDavison] - Secondary Problem: Figure1 is empty and should be the 3D plot, not the 2D plot.

[Solved using comment from TMDavison] - Tertiary Problem: The 3D plot (fig1) opens in a Window called Figure 2.

I want there to be 2 figures, each with 6 plots (for different values of alpha).

Thank you in advance for your patience and help with this problem.

```
# Test for plotting on multiple figures for multiple angles within a for-loop

#Import packages
import numpy as np 
from math import *
from astropy.table import Table 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

plt.close('all')

# define the initial conditions
x = 0               # initial x position
y = 0               # initial y position
z = 0               # initial z position

v = 30 
g = -9.8 

lst = [ 20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60] # launch angles    #https://www.journaldev.com/46432/vectors-in-python 
alpha= np.array(lst) 

def size(arr):
    if len(arr.shape) == 1:
        return arr.shape[0], 1
    return arr.shape

[nn,mm] = size(alpha)   #https://appdividend.com/2022/02/02/python-array-length/

#create plots:
ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')#fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

for kk in range(nn):#= 1:nn
    theta = alpha[kk]*pi/180.0

    t = 0               # starting at time 0
    Rmax = 800            # maximum range

    xtable = [0]
    ytable = [0]
    ztable = [0]  
    x3table = [x/3]
    y3table = [y/3]
    z3table = [z/3]

    h = 0.0100 
    tf = 200
    N=ceil(tf/h)
    for i in range(N):#for i = 1:N
        t = t + h #t(i+1) = t(i) + h

        # update position
        # output
        x = v*t*cos(theta)
        y = v*t*sin(theta) - ((0.5 * g) * (t ** 2))
        z = 0.1*x

        """ appends selected data for ability to plot"""
        #x_list.append(x)
        #y_list.append(y)
        #z_list.append(z)
        #v_list.append(v)
        xtable += [x]
        ytable += [y]
        ztable += [z]
        x3table += [x/3]
        y3table += [y/3]
        z3table += [z/3]
    x3table, y3table = zip(*sorted(zip(x3table, y3table)))
    ###############################################################################################################################
    ## figure 1 - 3 dimensional position
    # PLOT 1
    ###############################################################################################################################
    #fig1 = plt.figure(1) 
    #ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax1.plot3D(x3table ,z3table ,y3table)
    plt.title('Fig1 Test')
    #plt.savefig('Subtest_fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    #plt.clf()
    ###############################################################################################################################
    ## figure 2 - 2 dimensional position
    # PLOT 2
    ###############################################################################################################################
    #fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    ax2.plot(x3table ,y3table)#,'linewidth',2)
    plt.title('Fig2 Test')
    #plt.savefig('Subtest_fig2.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    #plt.clf()

plt.show()
```

Comment: you create ax1 with the `plt.subplots()` command. But then you create it again with `ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')`. Hence why its not on the figure you expect

Comment: @tmdavison Thank you, I made that change in the code above and it helped with problems 2 & 3, but was getting two lines of the same color for each plot now; i.e. 12 lines instead of 6. Maybe the last point is connecting to the first point? I sorted x3table and y3table, but still end up with a horizontal line across the top connecting max(y3table).

Comment: I think you might just want to redefine x,y,z = 0 at the top of the `for kk in range(nn)` loop, since currently you use them to initialise `x3table = [x/3]`, etc., but don't reset `x` before that.

Comment: @tmdavison, Thank you, I had actually done that and tried resetting x3table = y3table = [] following my plot, but that was when there were other issues. Things seem to be working as expected now.